# How to delete <br/> from Python crawling

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm using Python to crawl for the first time.
But I don't like the results.

Here's my simple code and result, the result I want.

```
**my code**

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'url'

webpage = urlopen(url)

source = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')

reviews = source.find_all('p', {'class':'desc_review'})

print(reviews)

for review in reviews :
    print(review.get_text().strip())
```

The output results for this code are as follows

```
[<p class="desc_review"> a1 </p>, 
<p class="desc_review">  </p>, 
<p class="desc_review"> b1
<br/>b2
<br/>b3 </p>, 
<p class="desc_review">  c1
<br/>c2 </p>, 
<p class="desc_review"> d1 </p>, 
<p class="desc_review"> e1 </p>]

a1
b1
b2
b3
c1
c2
d1
e1
```

But the result I want is this.

```
**want result**
[<p class="desc_review"> a1 </p>, 
<p class="desc_review">  </p>, 
<p class="desc_review"> b1 b2 b3 </p>, 
<p class="desc_review">  c1 c2 </p>, 
<p class="desc_review"> d1 </p>, 
<p class="desc_review"> e1 </p>]

a1
b1 b2 b3
c1 c2
d1
e1
```

As a result, I'd like to exclude br/.
What's the way?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to change parser to one less complex like "html.parser" and substitute the br tag with a space?